# Spring Integration: TCP Client/Server opening one client connection per server connection

Tags: java, spring, tcp, apache-camel, spring-integration

I'm trying to implement a TCP client/server application with Spring Integration where I need to open one TCP client socket per incoming TCP server connection.

Basically, I have a bunch of IoT devices that communicate with a backend server over raw TCP sockets. I need to implement extra features into the system. But the software on both the devices and the server are closed source so I can't do anything about that. So my thought was to place middleware between the devices and the server that will intercept this client/server communication and provide the added functionality.

I'm using a `TcpNioServerConnectionFactory` and a `TcpNioClientConnectionFactory` with inbound/outbound channel adapters to send/receive messages to/from all parties. But there's no information in the message structure that binds a message to a certain device; therefore I have to open a new client socket to the backend every time a new connection from a new device comes on the server socket. This client connection must be bound to that specific server socket's lifecycle. It must never be reused and if this client socket (backend to middleware) dies for any reason, the server socket (middleware to device) must also be closed. How can I go about this?

Edit: My first thought was to subclass `AbstractClientConnectionFactory` but it appears that it doesn't do anything except provide a client connection when asked. Should I rather look into subclassing inbound/outbound channel adapters or elsewhere? I should also mention that I'm also open to non-Spring integration solutions like Apache Camel, or even a custom solution with raw NIO sockets.

Edit 2: I got halfway there by switching to `TcpNetServerConnectionFactory` and wrapping the client factory with a `ThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory` and the devices can reach the backend fine. But when the backend sends something back, I get the error `Unable to find outbound socket for GenericMessage` and the client socket dies. I think it's because the backend side doesn't have the necessary header to route the message correctly. How can I capture this info? My configuration class is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class ServerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public AbstractServerConnectionFactory serverFactory() {
        AbstractServerConnectionFactory factory = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(8000);
        factory.setSerializer(new MapJsonSerializer());
        factory.setDeserializer(new MapJsonSerializer());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientFactory() {
        AbstractClientConnectionFactory factory = new TcpNioClientConnectionFactory("localhost", 3333);
        factory.setSerializer(new MapJsonSerializer());
        factory.setDeserializer(new MapJsonSerializer());
        factory.setSingleUse(true);
        return new ThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory(factory);
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter inboundDeviceAdapter(AbstractServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        TcpReceivingChannelAdapter inbound = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
        inbound.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return inbound;
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpSendingMessageHandler outboundDeviceAdapter(AbstractServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        TcpSendingMessageHandler outbound = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
        outbound.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return outbound;
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter inboundBackendAdapter(AbstractClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        TcpReceivingChannelAdapter inbound = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
        inbound.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return inbound;
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpSendingMessageHandler outboundBackendAdapter(AbstractClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        TcpSendingMessageHandler outbound = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
        outbound.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return outbound;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow backendIntegrationFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(inboundBackendAdapter(clientFactory()))
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO)
                .handle(outboundDeviceAdapter(serverFactory()))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow deviceIntegrationFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(inboundDeviceAdapter(serverFactory()))
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO)
                .handle(outboundBackendAdapter(clientFactory()))
                .get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking so I am going to assume that you mean you want a spring integration proxy between your clients and servers. Something like:

```
iot-device -> spring server -> message-transformation -> spring client -> back-end-server
```

If that's the case, you can implement a `ClientConnectionIdAware` client connection factory that wraps a standard factory.

In the integration flow, bind the incoming `ip_connectionId` header in a message to the thread (in a `ThreadLocal`).

Then, in the client connection factory, look up the corresponding outgoing connection in a Map using the `ThreadLocal` value; if not found (or closed), create a new one and store it in the map for future reuse.

Implement an `ApplictionListener` (or `@EventListener`) to listen for `TcpConnectionCloseEvent`s from the server connection factory and `close()` the corresponding outbound connection.

This sounds like a cool enhancement so consider contributing it back to the framework.

**EDIT**

Version 5.0 added the `ThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory` which would work out of the box with a `TcpNetServerConnectionFactory` since each connection gets its own thread.

With a `TcpNioServerConnectionFactory` you would need the extra logic to dynamically bind the connection to the thread for each request.

**EDIT2**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So51200675Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So51200675Application.class, args).close();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner() {
        return args -> {
            Socket socket = SocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket("localhost", 1234);
            socket.getOutputStream().write("foo\r\n".getBytes());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println(reader.readLine());
            socket.close();
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, String> fromToConnectionMappings() {
        return new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, String> toFromConnectionMappings() {
        return new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow proxyInboundFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(serverFactory()))
                .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
                .<String, String>transform(s -> s.toUpperCase())
                .handle((p, h) -> {
                    mapConnectionIds(h);
                    return p;
                })
                .handle(Tcp.outboundAdapter(threadConnectionFactory()))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow proxyOutboundFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(threadConnectionFactory()))
                .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
                .<String, String>transform(s -> s.toUpperCase())
                .enrichHeaders(e -> e
                        .headerExpression(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID, "@toFromConnectionMappings.get(headers['"
                                + IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID + "'])").defaultOverwrite(true))
                .handle(Tcp.outboundAdapter(serverFactory()))
                .get();
    }

    private void mapConnectionIds(Map<String, Object> h) {
        try {
            TcpConnection connection = threadConnectionFactory().getConnection();
            String mapping = toFromConnectionMappings().get(connection.getConnectionId());
            String incomingCID = (String) h.get(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID);
            if (mapping == null || !(mapping.equals(incomingCID))) {
                System.out.println("Adding new mapping " + incomingCID + " to " + connection.getConnectionId());
                toFromConnectionMappings().put(connection.getConnectionId(), incomingCID);
                fromToConnectionMappings().put(incomingCID, connection.getConnectionId());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory threadConnectionFactory() {
        return new ThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory(clientFactory()) {

            @Override
            public boolean isSingleUse() {
                return false;
            }

        };
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractServerConnectionFactory serverFactory() {
        return Tcp.netServer(1234).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientFactory() {
        AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientFactory = Tcp.netClient("localhost", 1235).get();
        clientFactory.setSingleUse(true);
        return clientFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow serverFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundGateway(Tcp.netServer(1235)))
                .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
                .<String, String>transform(p -> p + p)
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationListener<TcpConnectionCloseEvent> closer() {
        return e -> {
            if (fromToConnectionMappings().containsKey(e.getConnectionId())) {
                String key = fromToConnectionMappings().remove(e.getConnectionId());
                toFromConnectionMappings().remove(key);
                System.out.println("Removed mapping " + e.getConnectionId() + " to " + key);
                threadConnectionFactory().releaseConnection();
            }
        };
    }

}
```

**EDIT3**

Works fine for me with a `MapJsonSerializer`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So51200675Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So51200675Application.class, args).close();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner() {
        return args -> {
            Socket socket = SocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket("localhost", 1234);
            socket.getOutputStream().write("{\"foo\":\"bar\"}\n".getBytes());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println(reader.readLine());
            socket.close();
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, String> fromToConnectionMappings() {
        return new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, String> toFromConnectionMappings() {
        return new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    @Bean
    public MapJsonSerializer serializer() {
        return new MapJsonSerializer();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow proxyRequestFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(serverFactory()))
                .<Map<String, String>, Map<String, String>>transform(m -> {
                    m.put("foo", m.get("foo").toUpperCase());
                    return m;
                })
                .handle((p, h) -> {
                    mapConnectionIds(h);
                    return p;
                })
                .handle(Tcp.outboundAdapter(threadConnectionFactory()))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow proxyReplyFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(threadConnectionFactory()))
                .<Map<String, String>, Map<String, String>>transform(m -> {
                    m.put("foo", m.get("foo").toLowerCase() + m.get("foo"));
                    return m;
                })
                .enrichHeaders(e -> e
                        .headerExpression(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID, "@toFromConnectionMappings.get(headers['"
                                + IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID + "'])").defaultOverwrite(true))
                .handle(Tcp.outboundAdapter(serverFactory()))
                .get();
    }

    private void mapConnectionIds(Map<String, Object> h) {
        try {
            TcpConnection connection = threadConnectionFactory().getConnection();
            String mapping = toFromConnectionMappings().get(connection.getConnectionId());
            String incomingCID = (String) h.get(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID);
            if (mapping == null || !(mapping.equals(incomingCID))) {
                System.out.println("Adding new mapping " + incomingCID + " to " + connection.getConnectionId());
                toFromConnectionMappings().put(connection.getConnectionId(), incomingCID);
                fromToConnectionMappings().put(incomingCID, connection.getConnectionId());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory threadConnectionFactory() {
        return new ThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory(clientFactory()) {

            @Override
            public boolean isSingleUse() {
                return false;
            }

        };
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractServerConnectionFactory serverFactory() {
        return Tcp.netServer(1234)
                .serializer(serializer())
                .deserializer(serializer())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientFactory() {
        AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientFactory = Tcp.netClient("localhost", 1235)
                .serializer(serializer())
                .deserializer(serializer())
                .get();
        clientFactory.setSingleUse(true);
        return clientFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow backEndEmulatorFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundGateway(Tcp.netServer(1235)
                    .serializer(serializer())
                    .deserializer(serializer())))
                .<Map<String, String>, Map<String, String>>transform(m -> {
                    m.put("foo", m.get("foo") + m.get("foo"));
                    return m;
                })
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationListener<TcpConnectionCloseEvent> closer() {
        return e -> {
            if (fromToConnectionMappings().containsKey(e.getConnectionId())) {
                String key = fromToConnectionMappings().remove(e.getConnectionId());
                toFromConnectionMappings().remove(key);
                System.out.println("Removed mapping " + e.getConnectionId() + " to " + key);
                threadConnectionFactory().releaseConnection();
            }
        };
    }

}
```

and

Adding new mapping localhost:56998:1234:55c822a4-4252-45e6-9ef2-79263391f4be to localhost:1235:56999:3d520ca9-2f3a-44c3-b05f-e59695b8c1b0
{"foo":"barbarBARBAR"}
Removed mapping localhost:56998:1234:55c822a4-4252-45e6-9ef2-79263391f4be to localhost:1235:56999:3d520ca9-2f3a-44c3-b05f-e59695b8c1b0

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes that was exactly what I meant. I'm wondering if you meant `TcpNetClientConnectionFactory` instead of `TcpNetServerConnectionFactory`?

Comment: No; I mean that on the `ThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory` will work if the inbound factory is `Net` since each connection has its own reader thread. With the (inbound) NIO factory, requests will possibly be received on different threads, hence an enhanced client factory will be needed for that scenario. If it's not clear, I can put together a PoC tomorrow.

Comment: Edit: It seemed to work at first but then I ran into another problem could you take a look at my newest edit?

Comment: For request/reply messaging, use gateways instead of channel adapters and all the correlation will be done for you. `TcpInboundGateway` and `TcpOutboundGateway`.

Comment: I went with the adapter pairs specifically because it's not always request/reply messaging -- the clients and the server send and receive messages without expecting a reply

Comment: In that case you will need to maintain a reverse-directional map of `ip_connectionId` headers. When you receive a reply from the client-side, you will need to lookup the corresponding `ip_connectionId` and swap out the header from the client side with the looked-up header from the server side.

Comment: Hi, I can see what you did there but I still couldn't get it to work.. if I run it as-is, the backend server cannot listen on port 1235, and if I comment out the `serverFlow` bean, then the backend message doesn't go through to the client

Comment: It runs fine for me; what do you mean by "the backend server cannot listen on port 1235" ? The `serverFlow` is just to emulate your real backend.

Comment: Yes, I comment it out but then the backend -> device communication doesn't go through. I tried to add some logging to `proxyOutboundFlow` but it doesn't even get triggered

Comment: I'm on Spring Integration version 5.0.5 I don't know if that would make any difference..

Comment: Also, when I set serializer/deserializer to `MapJsonSerializer`

Comment: I am using 5.0.6 but it shouldn't make a difference; nor should the serializer, as long as it's configured correctly. DEBUG logging should help follow the messages through the flows.

Comment: Thanks. When I don't set serializer explicitly, I can't even see the backend message in the outbound flow. When I use `MapJsonSerializer` I can see the message in the logging code I added to the outbound flow, but it fails with exception `Unable to find outbound socket`. I put a breakpoint in `mapConnectionIds` and I noticed that `incomingCID` was null because the headers map was empty. I don't know if the the serializer is stripping the headers or if this is a bug. But everything worked fine when I explicitly set `ByteArrayLfSerializer` in all the connection factories.

Comment: Edit your question to show your serializer configuration and I'll take a look, but it might be tomorrow now.

Comment: It's basically the same as yours; except I set `ByteArrayLfSerializer` explicitly in the connection factories. If I set `MapJsonSerializer` then the message header comes in empty and the `mapConnectionIds` method fails because it tries to map to null. If I don't set any explicit serializer/deserializer, then the backend messages seem to be ignored

Comment: I changed my example to use a `MapJsonSerializer` with no problems, see EDIT3; so you must have something else incorrect.