# How do I setup Spring Integration Collaborating Channel adapters with Java annotations?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tcp, spring-integration, multiplexing

I have seen other posts related to my question but none of the answers have helped me solve my problem.

I was trying to follow the example here: https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/tcp-client-server-multiplex

I have a Spring Rest API that accept request, those request are changed into XML and then I send them to another application that accepts TCP request.

Using TcpOutboundGateway and TcpInboundGateway worked fine, but it was slow so I wanted to speed it up with collaborating channel adapters and multi plexing.

The idea (to my understanding) is to send a request through the gateway, that request is bridged to the aggregator, that request is also sent to the tcp server of the other application by the TcpSendingMessageHandler. Then the TcpReceivingChannelAdapter listens for responses, those responses are sent to the aggregator where they are correlated with their request (bc of the CORRELATION_ID header) and then sent to the transform channel that turns the bytes into string.

Obviously, my understanding is wrong because I don't see how the response gets back to the gateway and it's not working.

I can see the Socket being opened, but it is being closed immediately after the message is sent, so the deserializer is return an EOF: null error.

1. Did I setup the TcpReceivingChannelAdapter wrong?
2. How does the response get back to the gateway?
3. Should I use Future as the gateway response?

TCP config:

```
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@Configuration
public class TcpMultiPlexConfig implements ApplicationListener<TcpConnectionEvent> {

    protected final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TcpMultiPlexConfig.class);

    @Value("${engine.port}")
    private int port;// = 55001;
    @Value("${engine.address}")
    private String ipAddress;// = "192.168.1.1";
    @Value("${engine.timeout}")
    private int timeout;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(TcpConnectionEvent tcpEvent) {
        TcpConnection source = (TcpConnection) tcpEvent.getSource();
        if (tcpEvent instanceof TcpConnectionOpenEvent) {
            LOGGER.info("********* Socket Opened " + source.getConnectionId());
        } else if (tcpEvent instanceof TcpConnectionCloseEvent) {
            LOGGER.info("*********** Socket Closed " + source.getConnectionId());
        }
    }

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel="input")
    public interface MultiPlexGateway {

        String send(@Payload String in, @Header("CORRELATION_ID") String transactionId);

    }
    // TODO the request and response are being put together
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "input")
    public BridgeHandler bridge() {
        BridgeHandler bridge = new BridgeHandler();
        bridge.setOutputChannelName("toAggregatorClient");
        bridge.setOrder(1);
        return bridge;
    }

    @Bean
    public PublishSubscribeChannel input() {
        return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel toAggregatorClient() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel noResponseChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel toTransformerClient() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter inAdapterClient() {
        TcpReceivingChannelAdapter receivingAdapter = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
        receivingAdapter.setConnectionFactory(clientConnectionFactory());
        receivingAdapter.setOutputChannel(toAggregatorClient());
        receivingAdapter.setClientMode(true);
        return receivingAdapter;
    }


    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "input")
    public TcpSendingMessageHandler outAdapterClient() {
        TcpSendingMessageHandler outAdapter = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
        outAdapter.setOrder(2);
        outAdapter.setConnectionFactory(clientConnectionFactory());
        outAdapter.setClientMode(true);
        return outAdapter;
    }

    @Bean(name ="clientCFMP")
    public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory() {
        TcpNetClientConnectionFactory tcp = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(this.ipAddress , this.port);
        tcp.setSerializer(new DefaultSerializer()); // out
//      byte delimeter = "\n".getBytes()[0];
//      ElasticByteArrayRawSingleTerminatorSerializer deserializer = new ElasticByteArrayRawSingleTerminatorSerializer(delimeter);
//      DefaultDeserializer deserializer = new DefaultDeserializer();
        MyDefaultDeserializer deserializer = new MyDefaultDeserializer();
        tcp.setDeserializer(deserializer);

        tcp.setSoTimeout(timeout);
        tcp.setSingleUse(false);
        MapMessageConverter mc = new MapMessageConverter();
        mc.setHeaderNames("CORRELATION_ID");
        tcp.setMapper(new MessageConvertingTcpMessageMapper(mc));

        return tcp;
    }


    @MessageEndpoint
    public static class MyConverters {

        @Transformer(inputChannel="toTransformerClient", outputChannel = "resultToString")
        public byte[] getResponse(MessageGroup payload) {
//          byte[] result = null;
            List<Message<?>>list = new ArrayList<>(payload.getMessages());
            byte[] result = (byte[]) list.get(1).getPayload();
//          LOGGER.info(result);
            return result;
        }

        @Transformer(inputChannel="resultToString")
        public String convertResult(byte[] bytes) {
            String result = new String(bytes);
            LOGGER.info("*********** RESULT => " + result);
            return result;
        }

        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "noResponseChannel")
        public MessageTimeoutException  noResponse(String input) {
            throw new MessageTimeoutException("****** No response received for => " + input);
        }

    }



    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toAggregatorClient", outputChannel = "toTransformerClient")
    public FactoryBean<MessageHandler>  aggregatorFactoryBean() {
        AggregatorFactoryBean  afb = new AggregatorFactoryBean ();
        afb.setExpireGroupsUponCompletion(true);
        afb.setExpireGroupsUponTimeout(true);
        afb.setGroupTimeoutExpression(new ValueExpression<>(this.timeout));
        afb.setCorrelationStrategy(new HeaderAttributeCorrelationStrategy("CORRELATION_ID"));
        afb.setReleaseStrategy(new MessageCountReleaseStrategy(2));
        afb.setProcessorBean(new DefaultAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor());
        afb.setSendPartialResultOnExpiry(false);
        afb.setMessageStore(new SimpleMessageStore());
        afb.setDiscardChannel(noResponseChannel());
        return afb;
    }
```

Service that calls Gateway:

```
@Service
public class MultiPlexGatewayTransmission <T extends EngineData> extends AbstractMultiPlexEngineTransmission {

    public MultiPlexGatewayTransmission(MultiPlexGateway gateway) {
        super(gateway);
    }

    @Override
    public T request(EngineData request, Class<? extends EngineData> clazz) {
        String response = gateway.send(JaxbUtils.marshall(request), request.getApi().getMessageId());
        gateway.send(JaxbUtils.marshall(request), request.getApi().getMessageId());
        if(response == null || response.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOGGER.debug("MPGateway response ::: " + response.trim());
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T clientResponse = (T) JaxbUtils.unmarshall(response, clazz);
        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
//          LOGGER.debug("*** Unmarshall response ::: " + clientResponse);
        }
        return clientResponse;
    }
```

Test Case:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ITGetClientsTest extends AbstractEngineTest {

    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

//  @Autowired
//  private GatewayTransmission<ClientsResponse> transmission;

    @Autowired
    private MultiPlexGatewayTransmission<ClientsResponse> transmission;

    @Test
    public void testGetClients() {
        LOGGER.info("Gateway test testGetClients... ");

        Api api = new Api();
        api.setIp("192.168.1.1");
        api.setMessageId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        api.setVersion("1.0");      
        api.setUserToken(token);

        ClientsRequest request = new ClientsRequest();
        request.setApi(api);

        ClientsResponse response = (ClientsResponse) transmission.request(request, ClientsResponse.class);
        Assert.assertTrue(response != null);
        Assert.assertTrue(!response.getClient().isEmpty());

        LOGGER.info(Arrays.deepToString(response.getClient().toArray()));
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look at your code in detail; it's late, and a weekend, but see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200675/spring-integration-tcp-client-server-opening-one-client-connection-per-server-c/51201046#51201046) for a simpler, technique to use the inbound/outbound connection ids to correlate the request/reply.